# Is There A Way to Truncate by Words in View in Django?

Tags: python, json, django, serialization, truncate

I made a JSON serializer `to` view. I returned a `QuerySet` object which is called `entries` which looks for POST argument as below:

```
entries = blog.models.Entry.objects.filter(content__icontains=request.POST.get('q'))
```

Then I used `serializers` from `django.core`.

```
serializers.serialize("json", entries, fields=('title', 'content', 'created'))
```

This works like a charm, however, I want to return `content`s into truncated words.

---

## Environment

- Django 1.8.7
- Python 3.4

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the `Truncator` class from `django.utils.text`, for example:

```
from django.utils.text import Truncator
my_text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
n_words = 3
truncated_text = Truncator(my_text).words(n_words)
print(truncated_text)
# Lorem ipsum dolor...
```

`Truncator` can also truncate to a number of characters, and can parse HTML as well as plain text. While official docs appear to missing, the source code is pretty senf-explanatory, see: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/text.py

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.  Code-only answers are discouraged.

Comment: Thanks @Ajean - I added some context.

Comment: Thanks by providing answer.

Comment: How would I be able to use this with a rest framework `Serializer`?